# Add vi: ft without breaking the code

Tags: vimscript

I'm using `vim` to write `Jenkinsfile` which has a groovy synatx.

```
node {
  // Jenkins stuff to do
}
```

In order to force groovy syntax on a file without `.groovy` extension I added

```
# vi: ft=groovy
```

To the top of the file.

While this works in `vim` - `Jenkins` has issues treating this as groovy script and throws a `syntax error`.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` isn't how you write a comment in Groovy, so you've created a file with incorrect syntax.  Change it to a proper Groovy comment and you should be fine.

```
// vi: ft=groovy
```